# Laravel 4 Fluent Query Builder Join + Insert

Tags: mysql, join, insert, laravel

I am trying (without success) to execute a join + insert statement with the fluent query builder. Here is the offending code:

```
DB::table('lnk_users_languages')
  ->join('lut_languages', 'lnk_users_languages.lang_id', '=', 'lut_languages.id')
  ->where('lut_languages', 'lut_languages.lang_code', '=', 'en')
  ->insert(array(
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'lang_id' => DB::raw('lut_languages.id')
  ));
```

And here is my database structure:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE lut_languages;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lang_code | varchar(2)       | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| lang_name | varchar(30)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dominant  | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE lnk_users_languages;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lang_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And finally here is the error I receive:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lut_languages.id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `lnk_users_languages` (`user_id`, `lang_id`) values (?, lut_languages.id))
```

I assume the fluent builder does not anticipate join and insert statements to be used together as I can't find any documentation on it. Every example I find uses joins with selects. Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Just noticed an error in my fluent statement.

```
->where('lut_languages', 'lut_languages.lang_code', '=', 'en')
```

should be:

```
->where('lut_languages.lang_code', '=', 'en')
```

However, the error still persists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it does strips join on insert and delete statements. I had a ticket open to fix that, but it seems not all SQL Grammars support it. Can't say for sure if it's MSSQL or Postgre. Anyway, it didn't get accepted.

I recommend you to retrieve the language code first and then do a insert without join. Won't have much impact on performance or code size anyway.

```php
$language = DB::table('lut_languages')->where_lang_code($code)->first();
$user_language = DB::table('lnk_users_languages')->insert(array(
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'lang_id' => $language->id
));
```

Comment: Oh well, that's a shame. As you said, it wouldn't affect performance all that much. I was purely asking to satisfy my curiosity. Thanks

Comment: looks like its fixed now https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/57e11e392447206f60d77b33c0646229842315a3